# Problem on MySQL Query on Between Operator with php

Tags: php, mysql, between, difference-between-rows

I have MySQL table "room_booking" and this table contain two columns 'start_time' and 'end_time'. I want to check the time of the conference room booking. Suppose that if room is booked from 2:10 PM to 3:15 PM. Then another entry should not insert at between this time.
My query is

```
$queryCheck = "SELECT start_time,end_time FROM room_booking AND (SELECT * FROM (room_booking) WHERE (start_time NOT BETWEEN '".$new_start_time."' AND '".$end_start_time."') AND (end_time NOT BETWEEN '".$new_start_time."' AND '".$end_start_time."'))";
```

Answer (score 0):

This sounds to me to just be the overlapping range problem, and in this case you want to return records which do *not* overlap with the input start and end times.  Try this query:

```
SELECT *
FROM room_booking
WHERE existing_end < ? OR existing_start > ?;
```

To the two `?` placeholders above, you would bind, in order, `$new_start_time` and `$end_start_time`.  So, you would end up with the following query:

```
SELECT *
FROM room_booking
WHERE existing_end > $new_start_time OR existing_start > $end_start_time;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this one:-

```
INSERT INTO `room_booking` (`room`,`start_time`,`end_time`) 
SELECT 'A','2019-02-25 07:55:00','2019-02-25 08:00:00' FROM `room_booking`
WHERE NOT EXISTS
    (SELECT * FROM `room_booking` WHERE '2019-02-25 07:55:00' BETWEEN `start_time` AND `end_time`)
```

Let me know if you have doubt?

I am attaching screen shoot for an explanation[image].

[image]